# How to modify an item in-place (without copying / passing a buffer)

Tags: c, memory

I have often seen functions resemble the following in C:

```
do_something(buffer, original_data)
```

In which case, it takes the original data (often `const`) and returns the data that the user has asked for into the buffer. For example, a function like `gets` or `readline`.

What if there is a specific memory constraint on the program and there isn't space to return both the original data and the asked-for data. For example, what if there is 1GB of text data that needs to be sorted, and the user doesn't have 2GB available. What would be an example of a function (for example a sort function) that could run by modifying the data in-place?

Comment: Er... `qsort()`?

Comment: @Shawn yes, that would be fine -- could you show how that function itself would work (not calling it, but actually writing something like it).

Comment: @TagC198 When an array is passed to a C function, the function receives a pointer to the first element of the array. It can then modify the elements of the array as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard library function `qsort`.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
              int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

The array to be sorted is passed in `base`, its length in `nmemb`, the size of each element in `size` and the comparison function in `compar`.

Invocation looks something like this:

```
char **strings = NULL;
size_t nstrings = 0;
// do something to load strings;

//...

// sort the strings
qsort(strings, nstrings, sizeof(char *), string_comparer);


int string_comparer(const void *a, const void *b) { return strcmp(*(const char *)a, *const char *b); }
```

This API feels a little old and clunky because of the lack of a baton to pass to the function, but with the `gcc` extension allowing inner functions to access variables in outer functions this is no longer a real problem.

Somebody's mirror of glibc's `qsort` is here: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/qsort.c.html and a kernel version is here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8a72f3820c4d14b27ad5336aed00063a7a7f1bef/lib/sort.c

Comment: thanks for this. How does the qsort function itself work to sort items in-place rather than making a copy of the array?

Comment: @TagC198: It receives a pointer to the original data and writes to it via the pointer.